# jquery range slider values compared to outside value

Tags: jquery, json, rangeslider

I am using a range slider to display a range of prices, from 1000 to 3000.
Outside of the slider I have objects in a JSON file all of which have different prices. What i want to do is display the objects which price falls between the values the user has chosen.
This is my slider:

```
$(function() {
   $("#slider-range").slider({
       range: true,
       min: 1000,
       max: 3000,
       values: [1250, 2000],
       slide: function(event, ui) {
           $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
       }
   });
   $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
       " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

I guess what I think i should do is something like this?

```
if ((values = < data.objects[i].price) || (values => data.objects[i].price)) {
  //....
}
```